# Filter out Pivot Table values that derive from a small data group

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Given a dataset with given information: Date of Collection, Date of Departure and Price.

I have created a calculated value field finding the average price per quarter.

[Pivot Table with just Average Values per Time period (Quarter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce3Tx.png)

In order to find the average price per quarter Excel must aggregate the relevant data for each quarter in order to calculate. The number in each one can be found using a Count value field instead.

Additionally, one can even create a table with both values!

[Pivot Table with both Average and Aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl4le.png)

Is there a way to filter out values where there is less than say, 2000, data points supporting an average? By filter out, that could mean either making the cell empty or removing those points from the Pivot Chart.

Things I've Tried:
Using the built in value filter in Excel, (Count >2000). This appears to do absolutely nothing and perhaps my question should be about that.

I've also tried writing a macro to manually remove the raw data if it does not meet these requirements but this has proven very ineffective, I was hoping the built in Pivot tools can do this (or a macro related to them).

Comment: What I usually do is add another column with say "Y/N" value. And then in this column you use an if() that displays Y or N. And of course the if() should grab the "data" from a (or two) cell(s) that way you can control the ouput of the pivot table by changing one (or two) cell value (and updating the pivot table).

Comment: Oh.. and your "div/0"s can be removed with `=iferror(<calculation>,"")`

Comment: The errors are helpful because the PivotChart will just ignore them on the graph. They are ugly, but I'll only be showing the graphs to people luckily. I'll try your strategy.


@pnuts This could work, I would have to automate this but it's definitely a cleaner macro than the gargantuan I started to write. I'll think about it. Thanks for the lead!